# How can I print variable which is int from while loop and if else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, printing, count

The error I get from the program is undefined variable.

*

```
# Python 3.9.4
# import sys
# print(sys.version)

SubjectT = input("Enter your subject: ")
Tutor_Name = input("Enter your name: ")
Iterate = int(input("How many students are there? "))
# Set counter
# create count for each student
Accumulate = 0
for i in range(Iterate):  # It will run how many time based on Iterate input
    Score = float(input("Enter score: "))
    Counter = True
    while Counter:
        if 80 <= Score < 100:
            Accumulate1 = Accumulate + 1
        elif 80 > Score >= 65:
            Accumulate2 = Accumulate + 1
        elif 65 > Score >= 50:
            Accumulate3 = Accumulate + 1
        elif Score < 50:
            Accumulate4 = Accumulate + 1
        else:
            print("The number is a negative value or incorrect")
            Again = input("Enter yes for restarting again or if you want to exit the program please press anything: ")
            if Again in ("y", "Y", "YES", "Yes", "yes"):
                continue
            else:
                break
print(f"Subject title:", {SubjectT}, "\nTutor:", {Tutor_Name})
print("Grade", "     Number of students")
print("A", "Students: ", Accumulate1)
print("B", "Students: ", Accumulate2)
print("C", "Students: ", Accumulate3)
print("D", "Students: ", Accumulate4)
```

- 

This is my first post in Stackoverflow.
pardon me for any inappropriate content.
Thanks you so much.

Comment: if-elif statements are declaring variables, which might not always get executed and you at the end expecting all Accumulate 1,2,3 to be declared, causing said error.

Answer (score 0):

I realised why you had the While loop in there, but it still wasn't working for me effectively - if all answers were within range it never terminated. This should work for you, it does for me. I changed it so it checks every time somebody enters a score that it is within the correct range, so you don't have to repeat the whole loop in the event of incorrect values

```
SubjectT = input("Enter your subject: ")
Tutor_Name = input("Enter your name: ")
NoOfStudents = int(input("How many students are there? "))
# Set counter
# create count for each student
Accumulate = 0
Accumulate1 = 0
Accumulate2 = 0
Accumulate3 = 0
Accumulate4 = 0

def validRange(score):
    if 0 <= score <=100:
        return True
    else:
        return False
i = 1
while (i <= NoOfStudents):  # It will run how many time based on Iterate  

validInput = False
while (not validInput):
    Score = float(input("Enter score: "))
    if ( not validRange(Score)):
        print("The number is a negative value or incorrect")
    else:
        validInput = True
        if 80 <= Score < 100:
            Accumulate1 = Accumulate1 + 1
        elif 80 > Score >= 65:
            Accumulate2 = Accumulate2 + 1
        elif 65 > Score >= 50:
            Accumulate3 = Accumulate3 + 1
        elif Score < 50:
            Accumulate4 = Accumulate4 + 1
        i = i+1
    

print(f"Subject title:", {SubjectT}, "\nTutor:", {Tutor_Name})
print("Grade", "     Number of students")
print("A", "Students: ", Accumulate1)
print("B", "Students: ", Accumulate2)
print("C", "Students: ", Accumulate3)
print("D", "Students: ", Accumulate4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated

```
Counter = True
```

without iteration, thus it will run indefinitely. With while loop you need to set some constraints.